# Number of bounties offered by a user

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

Is it possible to see how many bounties offered a specific user and how many of these bounties were awarded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For any user, you can go to their profile and under activity you can choose the bounties tab. One of the things you can see there is the [list of offered bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

If you want to see how many bounties were actually awarded, I do not know about such possibility displayed directly on the site. But you can use [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) to get this (and various other things about bounties). When using SEDE, keep in mind that it is only updated once a week.

- You can get the questions where a specific user offered a bounty: [Questions where I offered a bounty](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1582773/questions-where-i-offered-a-bounty?userid=121097)
  .
- You can get the answers where a specific user awarded a bounty: [Answers that received bounties from me](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1417404/answers-that-received-bounties-from-me?userid=121097). (Although getting the bounties awarded by some user is a bit tricky - see [this conversation in the SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/conversation/how-to-get-bounties-awarded-by-a-specific-user).)
- As a complement: [Bounties from me awarded to no answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1417408/bounties-from-me-awarded-to-no-answer?userid=121097)

Considering my limited experience with SQL, you should take the above queries with a grain of salt. (But since I consulted them with a more experienced user in the SEDE chatroom, I suppose they should be fine.)